# How to prepend an item to Lua array?

Tags: lua

As title. I'm working with a neovim config, and the content of this array will be concatenated into a command to execute:

```
cmd = { 'mono', omnisharp_bin, '--languageserver', '--hostPID', tostring(vim.fn.getpid()) }
```

like this one but imagine that the `'mono'` has not been prepended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`table.insert`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.insert):

```
cmd = { omnisharp_bin, '--languageserver', '--hostPID', tostring(vim.fn.getpid()) }
table.insert(cmd, 1, 'mono')
-- cmd is now what you want
```

You can use either `table.insert(mytable, position, value)` to insert `value` at position `position` and shift all the values after that over, or use `table.insert(table, value)` to insert a value at the end of the array part.

Comment: Is there any difference in performance regarding the index to insert, e.g. first vs last index?

Comment: Yes, as far as I'm aware all Lua implementations implement the so called array part of tables as an actual array and as such inserting an entry in a table at the end is very fast, inserting an entry at index 1 is slower as it involves copying `#cmd` entries. For tables as small as yours, the time needed is trivial. But if you want to insert, say, a million entries, it's going to be about five orders of magnitudes times faster to append each entry to the end rather than inserting each at index 1.

Comment: Thanks for your further explanation!

Answer (score 1):

And imagine `cmd` is an object and can handle all by itself...

```
cmd = setmetatable({ omnisharp_bin,
 '--languageserver',
 '--hostPID',
 tostring(vim.fn.getpid()) },
 {__index = table}) -- This adds all table functions to cmd

cmd:insert(1, 'mono')

print(cmd:concat(' ',1 , #cmd))
-- As LMD wrote in comment, 1 and #cmd not really needed here
-- It shows concat()' default behaviour and could inspire
-- That you can pick with concat() a range of numbered keys
-- Or only one with: cmd:concat('', 1, 1)
-- Especially the zero and also negativ numbers
```

Important:
`cmd.insert()` means: Use from cmd
( like `table.insert(cmd, 1, 'mono')` )
`cmd:insert()` means: Use with cmd
( Without `cmd` as first argument )

Comment: The `1, #cmd` is unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

To answer it myself (since I was also diving into this question before I saw these answers. thanks):

```lua
cmd = { 'mono', unpack(cmd) }
```

I think this one *might* be slow, but it's simple so it's elegant.

Comment: What this basically does is: Push contents of `cmd` on the stack (unpack), pop and append to the `{ 'mono' }` table. This (1) does not prepend to the original table, but creates a copy (which might be what you want) and (2) is limited by the max stack size (which presumably is not an issue for your command arguments though).

It should not be slower than doing the same using a for-loop and `table.insert` and might even be faster.